# Renaming XSLT attribute value from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I have XSLT as below :-

```
 <ServiceRequest ExternalSystemName="ServiceNow" Company="{ServiceRequest-Company}">
      <xsl:if test="{ServiceRequest-LastResolvedDate} and {ServiceRequest-LastResolvedDate} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:attribute name="LastResolvedDate">
          <xsl:value-of select="{ServiceRequest-LastResolvedDate}" />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="{ServiceRequest-ServiceType} and {ServiceRequest-ServiceType} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:attribute name="ServiceType">
          <xsl:value-of select="'SR'" />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
...
...
```

I want to rename particular attribute name via C# code.

For that I had written below code :-

```
var property = root.Descendants(elementName).Descendants().Attributes("name").Where(x => x.Value == "LastResolvedDate");
                    foreach (var item in property)
                    {
                        item.Name = "renamed_new_name";
                    }
```

This code gives me error that atribute name cannot be assigned and is readonly.

[image]

What can be the possible solution?

**EDIT 1 :**

It is changing attribute name :-

```
<xsl:if test="LastResolvedOn/value and LastResolvedOn/value != ''">
                    <xsl:attribute renamed_new_name="LastResolvedOn">
                      <xsl:value-of select="LastResolvedOn/value" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:if>
```

Where I needed :-

```
<xsl:if test="LastResolvedOn/value and LastResolvedOn/value != ''">
                    <xsl:attribute name="renamed_new_name">
                      <xsl:value-of select="LastResolvedOn/value" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the existing attribute and add a new one, e.g.:

```
var elements = root.Descendants(elementName).Descendants()
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "LastResolvedDate");

foreach (var item in elements)
{
    item.Attribute("name").Remove();
    item.Add(new XAttribute("renamed_new_name", "LastResolvedDate"));
}
```

Comment: can you see Edit1. It is renaming name , but I wanted to rename value of name where name="LastResolvedOn"

Comment: @CSharper, int this case simply do `item.Attribute("name").Value = "renamed_new_name";`

Comment: @CSharper, btw, you question is `Renaming XSLT attribute name from C# code`, and should be `changing attribute value` in this case

Comment: Done. Thanks for noticing me out. This answer was really helpful